# UIWebview embedded in UIScrollView

Tags: video, html, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Before everyone says, "why are you using a uiscrollview in a uiwebview - the delegate methods will get confused" - let me say that I am creating an app whose content is HTML and am paging the content. My problem is that I am imbedding an HTML5 video in each of the pages that won't play for some reason:

Here is my snippet:

It will play in safari but not on my ipad or ipad simulator(4.2). Does the uiscrollview make a difference? Has anyone seen this before? I played the video from a static page on my ipad, but maybe the css is messing with it?

Thanks for any helpful suggestions...
mark

Comment: Oh, by the way... I used the html in a separate uiwebview and the video plays just fine. When I click the webview imbedded in the scrollview, the 'play' button changes color so it appears that I am getting a touch event - but no video begins to play?

Answer (score 1):

yes, after much headache I figured it out. I had

scrollView.delayContentTouches = YES;

Which meant that it would work but you had to hold the click for a second or so for the scrollview to figure out whether it was a swipe or not.

I also had a custom gesturerecognizer on the view that i wasn't using that took the event as well.

It worked if you held down the button for 3 seconds, but now it responds normally.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 4.3.1 create a new project. File -> New project -> Page-Based application. Drag and drop a UIWebView onto the storyboard.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252331